# Filezilla uploads at 80KB/Sec Max

Tags: 11.04, files

Am trying to upload files with Filezilla to my server and the upload is somehow limited to 80KiB. The server can take up to 4MiB in upload and my connection has a 512KiB upload.

What should I check to see what the problem is.

Comment: Have you used more than 80KiB/S before? Were you trying to upload at peak times?

Comment: Are you using FTP, SFTP, FTPS or something else? Check your filezilla configuration for any throttle settings.

Comment: When using scp o rsync I can go to the same server as fast as 440KiB. for the filezilla am using FTP and SSH. But if I use ssh from console via scp o rsync it goes faster than filezilla.

Comment: For the answer which should be question below the answer is for speedtest.net: 3876KiB Download / 480KiB Upload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that could be limiting your speed:

1. The receiving server: some servers limit up/download speeds depending on the protocol used (eg: I used to have a web hosting server that throttled HTTP downloads to 40 KB/s, but SCP worked full speed)
2. Your ISP (ie: your upstream speed limit): if this is the case the only choice is to upgrade
3. Your client (FileZilla): if you can upload with better speeds to the same server using the same protocol with a different client, it might be a setting on your client.

Comment: In my comment above I already explained that by using ssh or rsync I have a much better speed, so point 1 and 2 are not the problem. For point 3 I have not changed any of the default values for filezilla. Already checked for limiting options and none have something that says to limit my upload.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado Are you sure you are using the correct hostname and port for SFTP on Filezilla?

Comment: yeap. 100% sure. Already checked that. just in case am using the 3.3.5.1 version of filezilla that comes with 11.04

Answer (score 0):

use [speedtest.net](http://www.speedtest.net) to check your real upload and download speed.
usually the upload speed is half the download speed.

**Edit:** You may also check your speed limit settings for FileZilla which is located under `Edit > Settings... > Transfers > Speed Limits`.

Comment: This should be a comment. Already answered above in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are not confusing KiB with KB or something:

512KiB line is max: ((512*1000)/8)/1024=62.500KB max, don't know were you had your 80KB from but not from a 512KiB line I think.

Comment: Don confuse Kb with the IEC KiB. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibibyte 512KiB is 512 KiloBytes, that means 512KB/Sec in terms of transfer. Your equation is for bits and not bits exactly but human readable ones when you multiply by 1000 instead of 1024.

Comment: Oh sorry, gl with your quest to find a solution for this.